# Get distance of window from the top of document on page load (javascript only)

Tags: javascript, window, document, onload, offset

I've been having trouble calculating this on page load. It should only take one line but I can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 0):

could you elaborate on what the "distance of window to document" means? if you are looking for screen height/width:

```
window.screen.height
window.screen.width
```

or

```
window.screen.availHeight
window.screen.availWidth
```

for vertical scroll position use:

```
window.pageYOffset 
window.scrollY
```

I'm pretty sure they are equivalent i.e.

```
window.pageYOffset == window.scrollY; // always true
```

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. I meant the distance from the window to the top of the document. The offset. Like when you first open a page, it's zero since the window is at the very top of the document. But when you scroll down, there's a distance of pixels from the window to the top. You know what I mean?

Comment: Oh no problem, I think I see what you are saying. Have you tried using **window.pageYOffset** or **window.scrollY** ? I'm pretty sure they are equivalent i.e. window.pageYOffset == window.scrollY; // always true

Comment: Yeah, I tried using those, but it always equaled 0 on page load. I eventually concluded that when you load the page, the window is at the very top which registers a 0, and then insta-moves to the proper position (like if you refreshed while half way down the page or were linked to an #element). Does that makes sense? However, I was able to get the value by running pageYOffset through a window.onscroll function since once it insta-moves to the proper position, it counts as a scroll and runs the function. I didn't know it worked like that. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

DSOC (document scroll offset coordinates) can be found with window.pageXOffset and window.pageYOffset.  In your case, you want window.pageYOffset.

More details here:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/static2.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an old question, but I had the same problem and sought out a way to fix it. It appears that `window.scrollY` is not set directly on page load. However, if you do the following, it will register the correct value:

```
window.setTimeout(function() { console.log(window.scrollY); }, 10);
```

I've determined that the extra 10ms allows for the document to load and for it to set the `window.scrollY` value.